# React 18 & react-i18next Trans component interpolation issue

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I've just upgraded to `react v18` but I get an error while doing interpolation using `Trans` component of `react-i18next`

```
<Trans i18nKey="pageNrOfAll" pageNr={pageNr} pagesCount={pagesCount}>
    Page
    <strong className="spacing">{{ pageNr }}</strong>
    of
    <strong className="spacing">{{ pagesCount }}</strong>
 </Trans>
```

[image]

```
Type '{ pageNr: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pageNr' does not exist in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1375, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'
```

If I keep only one pair of brackets `{ pageNr }` I get the following error

> react-i18next:: Trans: the passed in value is invalid - seems you passed in a variable like {number} - please pass in variables for interpolation as full objects like {{number}}. 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s an open issue here: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1483

Just follow tge discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. That's the best I could come up with that also works with Typescript.

***App.jsx/App.tsx***

```
<Trans i18nKey="pageNrOfAll" values={{ pageNr: pageNr, pagesCount:pagesCount }}>
    Page
    <strong className="spacing"></strong>
    of
    <strong className="spacing"></strong>
</Trans>
```

Translation en-US of ***pageNrOfAll***

```
{
    "pageNrOfAll": "Page <1>{{pageNr}}</1> of <3>{{pagesCount}}</3>"
}
```

Translation pt-BR of ***pageNrOfAll***

```
{
    "pageNrOfAll": "Página <1>{{pageNr}}</1> de <3>{{pagesCount}}</3>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own component with any type as a workaround. This bypasses the TypeScript logic, but a quick replacement for larger project. In addition, you now have a central component to make formatting adjustments.

Before:

```
<Trans i18nKey="files.successFileUploaded">
    File <strong>{{ fileName: selectedFilename }}</strong> uploaded successfully!
</Trans>
```

After:

```
<Trans i18nKey="files.successFileUploaded">
    File <TransHighlight>{{ fileName: selectedFilename }}</TransHighlight> uploaded successfully!
</Trans>
```

New component:

```
import React from 'react';

interface TransHighlightProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode | any;
}

function TransHighlight(props: TransHighlightProps) {
  const { children } = props;
  return (<strong>{children}</strong>);
}

export default TransHighlight;
```